# Is there any detailed documentation explaining Apache Ignite thread pools?

Tags: ignite

I'm running a single node Apache Ignite server. What should be the best thread pool configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you analyzing the current performance and thread pool usage before changing the defaults that are good enough for most cases. Check [Thread Pools Tuning](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/perf-and-troubleshooting/thread-pools-tuning) documentation if you want to dive deeper.

Comment: Thanks @Alexandr Shapkin for the answer but the official Ignite documentation for thread pool tuning has little mentioned about it. I want to know for what all purposes threads are being used along with its internal mechanism.